# Firebase cloud function trying to merge users data into an array

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, merge, google-cloud-functions

I'm currently working on a React-Native project.
I'm building an app using Firebase.
Let's classify this as a social media app.

Using the firebase cloud function, I'm trying put all the users into a single document.
For that, using the onCreate event, im listening to every new documents created within the collection "users", and each time a new user is created I'm taking all his informations and put it into another document within a collection "aggregation". Giving this tree "aggregation/users".

Here is my code :

```
exports.aggregateNewUsers = functions.firestore
    .document('users/{userId}')
    .onCreate( (snapshot, context) => {

        const newUser = snapshot.data()
const aggUsersRef = db.doc('aggregation/users')

        return aggUsersRef.set({
users: [newUser]} 
, {merge: true})

    })
```

With this, i want each new users to be added within the fields users (an array).
I'm using the merge option to do so. But, maybe because im trying to use it with an array, it doesn't work and instead of keeping the old data and merging it with the new ones, it simply remplace it everytime a new user is created.
I also tried to use the mergeFields option without success because it throws an error.

Is there a way to make it works?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with arrays can be tricky. Here, ‘**merge**’ does not mean ‘**append**’, it means to replace (or add) values for properties that are part of the object passed in and leave the rest of the document alone.  Since you are passing in an object with an existing property (users), the value of that property is replaced.

To append an item in an array field (within Cloud Firestore), there are two methods:

1. Read the entire existing array, then append the new data to it, and finally, update the document with the modified array. Obviously, this is not a scalable solution if you expect to have many items in the array.
2. Use the Firebase ArrayUnion method

   ```
    aggUsersRef.update({
        users: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(newUser)
    });
   ```

Per the Firebase Cloud Firestore documentation:

"If your document contains an array field, you can use **arrayUnion**() and **arrayRemove**() to add and remove elements. arrayUnion() adds elements to an array but only elements not already present. arrayRemove() removes all instances of each given element."
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data

*Edited to include the solution found by the poster for other readers.*

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I was actually searching a better solution instead of having to read the entire array because as you said it's not the best one knowing this document will tend to have many items. I just found a solution that seems to work. Using the new Firebase solution "arrayUnion" and sending my newUser data to it each time one is created. I still had to set the merge option to true to make it works. With it, it append thr data correctly as they come and does not replace them anymore

Comment: Great find on that arrayUnion method! I've updated my answer to include an example for others that may have a similar question.